# QLibrary does not load

Tags: qt

I'm trying to write a simple example of loading a dll file, and the load fails.
I'm using qt 5.1.1 qt creator 3.0.1. 
my compiler is: Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 11.0 (amd64)

the pro file:

```
QT       += core

TARGET = rrrr

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

the main file is:

```
#include <QLibrary>

int main()
{

    bool is;
    QLibrary lib("C:\\A.dll");
    is = lib.load();
    is = lib.isLoaded();

    return 0;
}
```

The A.dll file of-course exists inside C.
I get the value false for the variable "is" while debbuging.

Comment: What does [lib.errorString()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlibrary.html#errorString) return? Does it work if you put the dll beside your executable and do `QLibrary lib("A");`? Also, why are you not creating a QCoreApplication?!

Comment: does the library match your applications' architecture ?

Comment: lib.errorString() returns: Cannot load library C:\A.dll:

Comment: It doesn't help if I put the dll besides the exe file.

Comment: I only want to be able to load a dll file, so i don't need now to create  a QCoreApplication.

Comment: What does it mean that the library matches the applications' architecture?

Comment: @user3563208: both are compiled with the same compiler, they are both either 32 bit or 64 bit, etc. Please do create QCA for a test. Perhaps, QLibrary needs that... No, putting beside the executable means you use `QLibrary lib("A");`, not the absolute path. Have you tried so?

Comment: Thanks. i figured the problem. It was that the DLL was 32 bit DLL and the process was 64.